# I want to spatial join two tables with the same polygons, so I only want to extract where the polygons does not merge with the other

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-join

I want to spatial join two tables with the same polygons, so I only want to extract where the polygons does not merge with the other.

```
SELECT  
       e.SGid as 'table_name2'
From [table] 
    inner join table2 e with (index = s123_idx, nolock) ON e.SHAPE.STWithin(j.Shape.STCentroid()) = 1
         where (SUBSTRING(j.SG_ID,1,8) + SUBSTRING(j.SG_ID,12,13)) <> e.SGid
```